# Failed memory segmentation in C

Tags: c

I was just practicing in C, writing some simple I/O applications. Test runs (Build&Run) went without any errors or warnings, but the actual app (and also debugger) is leaking memory.
*I simplified the app so it's now only the function that's leaking memory.*

```
char *new_name(char *old_name, char *operation)
{
    char file_num[2];

    char *edited_name = ( char* ) malloc( strlen( old_name ) + strlen( operation ) );
    strcat( edited_name, old_name );
    strcat( edited_name, operation );

    // Iterate through names of new file to see which doesn't exist
    int fnum = 1;
    char *tempname = ( char* ) malloc( strlen( old_name ) + strlen( operation ) + sizeof( file_num ) + sizeof( ".txt" ) );
    do
    {
        strcpy( tempname, edited_name );
        sprintf( file_num, "%d", fnum++ );
        strcat( tempname, file_num );
        strcat( tempname, ".txt" );
    } while ( file_exists( tempname ) );
    free(edited_name);

    return tempname;
}

int main()
{

    char *old_name = "textfile";
    char *operation = "_join";
    char *out_name = new_name(old_name, operation);

    printf( "%s", out_name );

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to change the malloc() "formulas" to int values just by counting the chars, but it doesn't seem to work for me (still I believe the problem is there, but I just can't solve it).

P.S. `file_exists` is very simple and just returns an **int**.

Comment: I see a call to `free` for `edited_name`, but not one for `tempname`.

Comment: you are using `malloc` on both `edited_name` and `tempname`, but you are only freeing `edited_name`.

Comment: You should `free(out_name)` at the end of `main` -- it's also memory obtained by `malloc`, even if that was in another function.

Comment: Your allocations need one more byte for the terminating null character. You should also set the first char to `'\0'` before `strcat`ting -- or replace the first `strcat` with a `strcpy`. Or maybe do everything in one go with `snprintf`.

Comment: Yeah, actually even feel stupid about that, I wanted to do it, but just forgot.
But still, I just `free(out_name)` after `printf` and still getting the same error

Comment: Actually that is, thank you. After doing all that (adding one byte and calling `strcpy()` first I was able to fix it. Thank you. I think you can make it an answer to this question if you want

Answer (score 1):

of course it is leaking memory.
There are two `malloc`s, but only one `free`.

you have to `free` the `out_name` before leaving main and after last usage of it.

Comment: So, I just tried `free(out_name)` and still seem to get the same error.

Comment: it seems that your allocated buffers are to small and calling the copy routines may end up writing behind the allocated memory region that is undefined behavior. So maybe this is the source of the error. please fix your allocations and recheck.

Comment: I've already solved the problem. Actually it was multiple problems, so by solving each of them I was able to run the program normally. I should have to 1) allocate 1 more byte for the terminating null char, 2) use `strcpy` before `strcat` and of course 3) `free(out_name)`.
It worked fine for me after all that done.